# Recent Bitlocked drive won't unlock with key, says it cannot find TPM though TPM is present and verified within a dual-boot setup

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

Dual-boot Windows 10 OS with two different boot SSD drives. One was already encrypted against the motherboard TPM for some time and continues to boot successfully. I enabled encryption on the second drive, followed prompts, rebooted when asked and it gets to the "Enter the recovery key page" with the error "Bitlocker needs your recovery key to unlock your drive because the trusted platform module is not accessible." It then lists the key ID - which matches what I have in my MS account recovery details.

Entering this key causes a reboot and a repeat of the above cycle.

Existing working bitlocked encrypted drive is running 1903 latest, the one not working is running 1809 latest.

Mounted the offending drive in the Widowsn 10 OS that boots. It prompts me for the 48 digit recovery key. I enter the correct one (the only one uploaded today to my account) and it says it does not match. On the off chance, I tried other recovery keys for same PC but didn't match either.

Tried cmd command `manage-bde -unlock G: -rk <key>` and it  gives me "ERROR: An error occurred while attempting to read the key from disk."

Looks like corruption. Anyone encounter this before and identified a recovery option?

The status info I can get is as follows:

manage-bde -status G:
BitLocker Drive Encryption: Configuration Tool version 10.0.18362
Copyright (C) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Volume G: [Label Unknown]
[Data Volume]

```
Size:                 Unknown GB
BitLocker Version:    2.0
Conversion Status:    Unknown
Percentage Encrypted: Unknown%
Encryption Method:    XTS-AES 128
Protection Status:    Unknown
Lock Status:          Locked
Identification Field: Unknown
Automatic Unlock:     Disabled
Key Protectors:
    TPM
    Numerical Password
```

Answer (score 1):

Possible recovery option: Use any Linux system with *dislocker* installed on it. You can either open the volume using `dislocker-fuse` or permanently decrypt the partition in-place with `dislocker-file`. (But better don't do any in-place changes unless you're 100% sure the disk is good.)

The option `-p` lets you specify the numeric recovery key and `-v -v` will show exactly how far it's able to open the volume before giving up.